# getWritableDatabase called recursively

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm attempting to update my database table with the following code:

```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        String query = "ALTER TABLE names ADD COLUMN hidden integer default 0";
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);

    }
```

However, when I start the application and it tries to upgrade the database I get the following exception:

```
    ...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue and what exactly is causing it?

Thanks

Comment: this can't be the only place this part of the code gets called is it?

Comment: Yes, this is the only place the code is called.  I put a log statement in the function as well and it is only called once.

Comment: Then do a check if old version is < new version.this will make it exclusive, although I am not sure why it is being called multiple times.

Comment: onUpgrade() should only be called when the old version < new version anyways, right?  Also, since the log statement is only printed once, the function is only being called once.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't call `getWritableDatabase()`. Use the one passed in:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String query = "ALTER TABLE names ADD COLUMN hidden integer default 0";
    db.rawQuery(query, null);

}
```

Why? When you call `getWritableDatabase()` the OpenHelper is detecting that the database needs to be updated, hence it starts up the recursion warning you're seeing. In other words, you're in `onUpgrade()`. You call `getWritableDatabase()`, which sees an upgrade is needed. Were it not for the check, you'd be right back into `onUpgrade()`, ad infinitum.

Comment: So... what if you are migrating data that requires the use of utility classes instead of simple db.rawQuery or db.execSQL statements? I need to migrate/manipulate data to complete an upgrade.