# getDatabase called recursively when insert a record in oCreate of my DbHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

When I'm trying to insert a record in onCreate method of my DbHelper class which is extended from SQLiteOpenHelper, this error will be rised.
I've found some similar topics like these:
[Android getDatabase called recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066507/android-getdatabase-called-recursively)
[getWritableDatabase called recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152907/getwritabledatabase-called-recursively)
[getDatabase called recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955799/getdatabase-called-recursively)
but these are not going to help me.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public int x=0;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "shareholders.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (name text,value text)";
            Log.d("Ehsan", sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", "Username");
        cv.put("value", "");
        insert("settings", cv);

        cv.put("name", "Password");
        cv.put("value", "");
        insert("settings", cv);

        cv.put("name", "PersonId");
        cv.put("value", "");
        insert("settings", cv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


public long insert(String table,ContentValues cv){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb =this.getWritableDatabase();
    return mydb.insert(table,null, cv);
}

    }
```

the error will be raised when this line of code wants to execute:

```
insert("settings", cv);
```

Log Cat:

```
11-10 11:46:53.325: W/dalvikvm(19579): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    ... 11 more
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at ClassLibrary.DbHelper.insert(DbHelper.java:76)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at ClassLibrary.DbHelper.onCreate(DbHelper.java:56)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at ClassLibrary.DbHelper.insert(DbHelper.java:76)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at com.example.shareholders.entities.Person.insert(Person.java:99)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at com.example.shareholders.Sync.doSync2(Sync.java:71)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    at com.example.shareholders.AppMenu.clickHandler(AppMenu.java:56)
11-10 11:46:53.325: E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    ... 14 more
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a custom `insert()` method. It likely calls `getWritableDatabase()` which calls `getDatabase()` and it will throw this exception since `onCreate()` is already called in the context of `getDatabase()`. Just use `db.insert()` directly where `db` is the `SQLiteDatabase` object passed to your `onCreate()`, without calling `getWritableDatabase()`. This is essentially the same issue and solution as in all the three questions you linked.

Previously your question had another, prior problem the solution to which is below, with the `insert()` fix from above included:

Your table does not have the column names you specify in `ContentValues`.

There's only `name` and `value` columns specified in the `CREATE TABLE settings` but you're trying to insert data into columns `Username`, `Password` and `personId`.

It's also useful to log full exception stack traces (and not just the message), and to read the exceptions wherever you log them.

If I understand your intent correctly, you want either three name-value pair rows like this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name", "Username");
cv.put("value", "");
db.insert("settings", cv);

cv.clear();
cv.put("name", "Password");
cv.put("value", "");
db.insert("settings", cv);

cv.clear();
cv.put("name", "personId");
cv.put("value", "");
db.insert("settings", cv);
```

or a table with single row and the given columns:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (Username text,Password text,personId)";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, It was my mistake but the problem still remains :( I've updated my code in my Question.

Comment: @ehsanshirzari Looks like you're using a custom `insert()` which causes the recursion. Updated the answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that I want to do an Insert in onCreate of database. If it's forbidden to do this, how can I do this after creating database?

Comment: There is no any static insert method in SQLiteDatabase. what's your mean of: SQLiteDatabase.insert() ? Log cat in the question.

Comment: Use the `SQLiteDatabase` instance `db` that is passed to your `onCreate()`.